# How can I create a WordPress dynamic download counter

Tags: php, audio, wp-filesystem

I am creating a WordPress website that enable customers to download music and I want to track downloads and display the results next to the WordPress download button. I am using the WordPress convert audio to file to enable them to download the audios..

Comment: What is "WordPress convert audio to file"? A plugin?

Comment: How are the downloads served? Is it straight from a file on the filesystem or does it go through some PHP file? If it's through a PHP file you should be able to count the downloads there. If not there may be a way to hook into your web server to log them as they happen, else you might have to process the access logs e.g. every hour to spot new downloads.

Comment: @vancoder I am new to WordPress so I am not familiar with the terms used, but what I was trying to say is that  I upload my audios in the wp media library and then on the new post ,I add  a title and some content text which I want to display when a user clicks the permalink to the post. I then add a block (audio) below the content text . This upload the audio in the post .I then press the change block type and set transform to file . This then makes the audio to disappear and a download button appears.so the user clicks the button to download the audio...

Comment: @vancoder The goal is now to track and display the number of times that certain file is downloaded and display the count beneath the download button ..